# Definir configurações customizadas para o banco de dados no Laravel

Tags: laravel, banco-de-dados

Minha situação é seguinte, tenho varias configurações com o banco de dados definidas no arquivo *databade.php*, até aqui tudo bem. Mas existem  algumas conexões que necessitam de dados 'variáveis', como por exemplo o nome do banco.

Minha dúvida é se é possível definir esses dados 'variáveis' dentro do controller, como no Framework Codeigniter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410049/laravel-4-connect-to-other-database

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$conn = array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'DATABASE',
    'username'  => 'USERNAME',
    'password'  => 'SOME_PASSWORD',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
);

Config::set('database.connections.DB_CONFIG_NAME', $conn);
```

Nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410049/laravel-4-connect-to-other-database) tem outras opções.