# Autenticar em um banco de dados e alterar informações em outros

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5

Então, preciso criar uma aplicação com Laravel 5 onde seja possível diferentes usuários serem autenticados em um database específico onde está o sistema.

Após logar, cada usuário poderá alterar informações dentro do sistema, sendo que essas informações devem ficar em outro servidor, outro banco de dados. Cada usuário irá alterar informações em um banco de dados diferente.

Minha ideia é que quando o usuário for autenticado, já fique definido qual é o banco de dados dele, o banco que está vinculado ao login dele, para que ele possa alterar o que quiser. A aplicação deve saber qual banco de dados alterar de acordo com o usuário que está logado.

Não sei se consegui explicar direito, mas resumindo, a aplicação será apenas uma ponte que ligará cada usuário ao seu banco de dados, sendo que o login de todos deve ser centralizado em um banco de dados "principal".

Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como fazer isso? Existe algum "pacote" que eu possa usar?

> OBS: Não posso ficar criando diversas conexões no config/database.php.

As informações para conexão ficarão no banco de dados da aplicação principal, atrelado ao cadastro do usuário que será autenticado. Isso tem que ser dinâmico, verificar as informações de host e etc quando o usuário logar e já realizar a conexão com o banco de dados dele.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um middleware que pega as informações do bd do usuário autenticado e define uma nova configuração de banco:

```
$conn = array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'DATABASE',
    'username'  => 'USERNAME',
    'password'  => 'SOME_PASSWORD',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
);

Config::set('database.connections.bd_dinamico', $conn);
```

e quando quiser utilizar as configurações do banco utilize no escopo da classe:

```
protected $connection = 'bd_dinamico';
```

ou

```
public function method()
{
    $this->setConnection('bd_dinamico');

    $this = $someModel->find(1);

    return $something;
}
```

Desta maneira você irá estar trabalhando com os dados dentro da sua conexão dinâmica

*Referências:*

- [Definir configurações customizadas para o banco de dados no
  Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102382/definir-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es-customizadas-para-o-banco-de-dados-no-laravel?rq=1)
- [Múltiplos schemas no banco de dados Laravel 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82557/m%C3%BAltiplos-schemas-no-banco-de-dados-laravel-5)